# Trinomial Trees for Hull-White model

Tags: interest-rates, binomial-tree, hullwhite, trinomial-tree

I am studying trinomial trees and trying to implement them in Python to compare them to the monte carlo simulation. I searched 3-4 hours in the web; but can't find any implementation on binomial or trinomial trees online.

Very simple question by a beginner: is there any place to get more information on the implementation? Or atleast how to start?

Comment: I gave this answer a while back: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/33223/trinomial-tree-vba-code/33275#33275  The code is in VBA and  is very outdated and should be refactored but works just as well. You should be able to use it as a template for another language.

Comment: Brigo and Mercurio wrote a great book on interest rate modelling in 2006. It includes a chapter on the construction of trinomial trees for the Hull White model

Comment: You can check out FinancePy. The HW implementation is at https://github.com/domokane/FinancePy/blob/master/financepy/models/FinModelRatesHW.py

Answer (score 1):

I am also utilizing trinomial tress for a research project, implementing a GMDB rider, using a trinomial tree Hull-White model, however, with a slight modification in probabilities by using Eric Ulm's HJB equation.

Anyways, I am going to start using this James Ma's boyle trinomial as the base code.

https://github.com/jamesmawm/Mastering-Python-for-Finance-source-codes/blob/master/B03898_10_codes/TrinomialTreeOption.py